# Add to cart all product in views - Uber Cart

Tags: views, ubercart

Hi Everyone, I'm using Ubercart for my site.

I have some products. So now I want to build a views that display products as a

table, in this table each row has a column named "quantity", allow user decide

how many product he want to buy.

At the bottom of this view has "add to cart button", so It will add to user

cart all product has quantity > 0 in this views.

Like that

Product 1
$10
Quantity : textfield

Product 2
$20
Quantity : textfield

--Add to cart button--

How can I do that. Thanks